# Does Android SNEP server support fragmentation?

Tags: nfc, nfc-p2p

Does anyone here have experience sending fragmented SNEP message to android?

I tried sending large SNEP message to android using SNEP fragmentation as defined in NFC forum specs (shown on figure 3 and figure 6 in SNEP spec document).

After sending first fragment (complete SNEP header + data chunk), android replies with Continue response. As defined in SNEP spec, i send remaining data (without header) to android. After all data sent android never gives Complete response. Is it because my wrong sending sequence or android just doesn't support SNEP fragmentation?

I use Google Nexus S with android 4.1.2 and reader from chinese manufacturer with proprietary SDK.

Answer (score 2):

Android SNEP does support fragmentation. I use this all the time when I send out 20kb test messages via SNEP. The problem must be in your implementation.

I suggest that you take a look at the SNEP Android code to find out why you don't receive the confirmation. The code is here:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Nfc/+/ics-plus-aosp/src/com/android/nfc/snep/

Comment: How did you implement custom fragmentation? or is it in built in android? I can send multiple records but not multiple messages